# How to get rid of Jagged Lines around shadows in Evee Render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm extremely new to blender and I've come across a minor irritating thing.

While I'm trying to change the light around in Evee the shadows formed have these annoying jagged lines around them - [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZOoi.jpg). In Maya (IIRC) there was an option in the viewport settings to switch on Anti-Aliasing and this would be resolved. I have checked around Stack Exchange and even messed around with the Film setting but all it does is give the objects a blur.
This is my Render Setting - [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iesNR.jpg).

Is this something common with Evee that i have to get used to? Apart from  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: EDIT: I'm using blender v2.81a

Comment: Look under "Shadows" settings (Image 2) - Make sure "high bitdepth" is checked, see if you want soft shadows or not, and if things are still problematic, increase the shadow cubemap size.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank you. Increasing my cube and cascade size to 4096 solved the issue. I didn't have to check High Bitdepth. I'm a bit curious is this a part of a standard workflow?

Comment: Generally you want to keep the cube and cascade size as small as possible to have less performance impact. It's one of those "only increase if/when it's needed" kind of things. If you have a large scene with lots of shadows, you'll see the impact.

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.